# acceder a una variable global con js

Tags: javascript

tengo una variable global(gramosHc) a la cual modifico desde una función, pero cuando quiero acceder a ella en otra funcion se reinicia a cero

```
totalHc = document.getElementById('cant-hc');
var gramosHc =0;

//funcion para calcular los gramos según la calorías
function calNutriente(obj) {
  calculo = (obj.value * reinicio) /100;
    gramosHc = calculo/4;
}

//calculadora de calorias
function calculadora(obj) {

  /*...
   codigo para calcular calorías*/

   totalHc.value = cantHc  +'/' + gramosHc + ' gr de hc';
   //valor que tomara el input en la vista
}
```

no tomen en cuenta cantHc

Comment: Las variables globales están desaconsejadas porque pueden producir el efecto que mencionas, que sean modificadas desde otra parte de tu app sin saberlo o sin darte cuenta. Para entender qué puede estar colisionando y reproducir tu problema, haría falta algo más de contexto, ya que en el código el único punto que asigna cero es en la segunda línea, y sin ver más, la intuición dice que el flujo debe estar pasando por ahí o que el cálculo de los gramos llega a ser cero. Por otro lado, la variable `calculo` de esa función no está definida ni con var/let/const. ¿podrías aclarar un poco más porfa?

Comment: Gracias por responder, encontré el problema se debía a mal nombramiento de una variable, igual manera gracias por el consejo